# Best Practices concerning initComponent() in Ext.define()

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm writing all my components in ExtJS's new MVC fashion using `Ext.define()`.

I struggle a bit whether define properties inside of `initComponent()` or by simply setting them like `property: 42,`.

Are there widely accepted best practices?

I'm staggering between using `initComponent()` only when necessary (ie. when I want something dynamic or set a scope) which keeps the function shorter and spares me some ugly `this.`s and using it always which has the benefit, that I'd never have to move former properties to `initComponent()` just because I want to make it more dynamic.

Unfortunately, Sencha's docs don't tell much about that and the available examples seem to do as they want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personal practice, I will declare variables in the properties area when the

- variables defining magnitude, like `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`
- variables that awaiting to be overridden, or customizable, like `title`, `saveBtnTxt`, `url`, `fields`, `iconCls`
- some constants, that will have special prefixes so will not be overridden so easily

Then I will declare `items`, `listeners`, `this.on`, `Ext.apply(me, {..})` or anything that requires the scope of the obj (`this`, `me`), to sit inside my `initComponent`. Or stuff that should be modified/overridden before everything is setting up so user will not break my component by overriding some of the important variables.

Of course that'll serve as my guidance. 2 cents

**EDIT**

About the ugly `this`, I have used the variable `me` widely in my app, and it looks a lot cleaner than `this`. It benefits me from changing scopes less frequently too.

Comment: Okay, that would be my current approach. It just got tedious when certain properties magically became dynamic, that's why I'm asking. Didn't know about `me` yet...I'm pretty new to ExtJS.

Comment: No magic here. Just check their source code, you will see a lot of 'me' just flying around. 'me' is just a ref to the object 'this' actually.

Comment: The magic was refering to my own code, when I changed my mind and made a property dynamic. Because the lack of solid ExtJS 4 tutorials when I started out, my app got a bit dirty (ie. 3.2 style) and I had to rewrite a lot to make it MVCey. That lead to a lot of pulling properties inside of `initComponent()` which was a bit tedious. So is there any difference between `me` and `this` beside the fact it's shorter?

Comment: Shorter, yes, and you probably no need to change scope that frequently as you can always use 'me' in your code. Btw just my opinion, since they don't provide tutorials, learn from their code. It helps me quite a lot :)

Answer (score 11):

I want to add to Lionel's answer that it is better to declare any **non-primitive** config in `initComponent`. (By primitive I mean string, boolean and number). Array and Object go into `initComponent`.
So definition should look like this:

```
Ext.define('My.NewClass', {
  extend: 'OldClass',
  // here all primitive configs:
  cls: 'x-my-cls',
  collapsible: true,
  region: 'west',
  // and so on ...

  initComponent: function() {
    // here you declare non-primitive configs:
    this.tbar = [/* blah-blah */];
    this.columns = [/* blah-blah */];
    this.viewConfig = {/* blah-blah */};
    // and so on ...

    this.callParent(arguments);
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

The reason why you should put all non-primitive configs into initComponent is that otherwise configs of all instances will refer to the same objects. For example if you define NewClass like:

```
Ext.define('My.NewClass', {
  extend: 'OldClass',
  bbar: Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
  // ...
```

`bbar`s of all instances will refer to the same object. And therefore every time you create new instance bbar disappears from the preveous instance.

Comment: While I agree with you, I think this answer might be slightly misleading. My understanding is that if rather than creating an instance one uses xtype (that is, the object config), it won't be shared. Thus, in ExtJS 4 at least, there shouldn't be a problem having objects and arrays as config properties (compared to using InitComponent). Of course, if you need access to this or your class might be overridden by others or you need to merge configs, InitComponent is to be used. For more see: http://skirtlesden.com/articles/config-objects-on-the-prototype

Comment: What if you put it inside a "config {}" block?

Comment: one silly question I guess, but I would like to know what are non-premitive in extjs ? I know its arrays object etc.. but concept wise I am always confused to differentiate while creating an app in extjs 5. Does it harm the performance if I am not using `initComponent()` ?? I am a new in extjs btw. thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
  Ext.define('My.Group', {
// extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
xtype : 'fieldset',
config : {
    title : 'Group' + i.toString(),
    id : '_group-' + i.toString()

},
constructor : function(config) {
    this.initConfig(config);

    return this;
},    
collapsible: true,
autoScroll:true,
.....
});
```

you can use it as follow.

```
handler : function() {                      
        i = i + 1;
        var group = new My.Group({
            title : 'Group' + i.toString(),
            id : '_group-' + i.toString()
        });
        // console.log(this);
        // console.log(group);
        Ext.getCmp('panelid').insert(i, group);
        Ext.getCmp('panelid').doLayout();
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting your answer exactly but this comment is unrelated too: I like traffic lights

Comment: yea.. He is asking for opinion I guess :)

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't even contain a `initComponent()`. :) But traffic lights are awesome.

Comment: what do you mean by traffic lights?

Comment: Please consider creating a new question if you want to know something about traffic lights.