# What is the correct way to subclass Ext JS components?

Tags: extjs4.1

Which is correct way to extend/subclass components?

```
Ext.define('Holidays.Components.UserInfo', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.UserInfo',
region: 'west',
split: true,
title: 'Categories',
width: 300,
collapsible: true,
layout: 'border',
animCollapse: false,

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    Ext.apply(me, {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            border: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 2',
            region: 'south',
            collapsible: true,
            height: 200
        }, ]
    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Or this:

```
Ext.define('Holidays.Components.UserInfo', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.UserInfo',

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    Ext.apply(me, {
        width: 300,
        collapsible: true,
        layout: 'border',
        animCollapse: false,
        region: 'west',
        split: true,
        title: 'Categories',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            border: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 2',
            region: 'south',
            collapsible: true,
            height: 200
        }, ]
    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

When I create an instance of my class using first version, like this

```
this.userPanel = Ext.create("Holidays.Components.UserInfo");
```

my panel has animation when colapsed and I get weird layout behaviour.

Which properties I can set in define and which I must in initComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the full explanation for your title question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871594/best-practices-concerning-initcomponent-in-ext-define). Please also read the comment I've left to Molecular Man and have a look at the link included in my comment.

I'm not sure why you get this weird behaviour with the first version, for all I know this shouldn't be the case. Could you perhaps let us know what happens when using the first version, but having the `layout` and `animCollapse` configs in InitComponent? Also, is there a chance you create this component more than once?

Comment: I'll try to create more instances and see what happens then. I'm rewriting whole layout right now, but all the time I'm still a beginner and learning all the time, so I was wondering what are best practises, to start properly :)

Comment: Rewriting component from scratch helped. I don't know why, but now it works perfect :)