# ExtJs 4: Using two copies of same component in one form

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs4

Would like to ask your help in understanding how ExtJs4 extends components and solve the problem below.

I created custom `ItemSelector` component by extending `Ext.data.Grid`, which have `_aSelectedItems` property.

```
Ext.define("Ext.ux.ItemSelector", {
    extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",

    // @type {Array}
    _aSelectedItems: [],
    ...
    getSelectedItems: function() {
        return this._aSelectedItems;
    },
});
```

**Components**

After that I've created two components which use `ItemSelector` widget as an item:

```
Ext.define("components.Devices", {
    extend: "Ext.form.FieldContainer",
    _oDevicesSelector: null,
    ...
    _getSelector: function(oConfig) {
        if (!this._oDevicesSelector) {
            this._oDevicesSelector = new Ext.ux.ItemSelector({
                id: oConfig.id,
                name: oConfig.name,
                flex: 1,
                storeUrl: oConfig.storeUrl
            });
        }
        return this._oDevicesSelector;
    },

    getValue: function() {
        return this._getSelector().getSelectedItems();
    }
});
```

and

```
Ext.define("components.Firmwares", {
    extend: "Ext.form.FieldContainer",
    _oFirmwaresSelector: null,
    ...
    _getFirmwareSelector: function(oConfig) {
        if (!this._oFirmwaresSelector) {
            this._oFirmwaresSelector = new Ext.ux.ItemSelector({
                id: oConfig.id,
                name: oConfig.name,
                flex: 1,
                storeUrl: oConfig.storeUrl
            });
        }
        return this._oFirmwaresSelector;
    },

    getValue: function() {
        return this._getFirmwareSelector().getSelectedItems();
    }
});
```

In each of components above I create new instance of `ItemSelector` through `new`.

**Form**

I create a form, and push `components.Firmwares` and `components.Devices` into it.
All work properly, items load correctly.

**Issue**

When I select some items in `components.Devices` and call `getValue()` I get next results:

```
console.log( this.getDevicesSelector().getValue() );
// ["7885"] - it's OK

console.log( this.getFirmwaresSelector().getValue() );
// ["7885"] - but this array should be empty, 
// 'cause I didn't select any items in components.Firmwares selector
```

Can anyone help me to understand such behavior and how to fix it?

Really thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extending components/classes, non-primitive types (like your `_aSelectedItems` array) are shared between all class instances.

The full explanation for why this odd thing happens can be found in [this Skirtle's Den article](http://skirtlesden.com/articles/config-objects-on-the-prototype). You may also want to have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871594/best-practices-concerning-initcomponent-in-ext-define), and note my comment to Molecular Man's answer.

If you put your array within `initComponent` your issue should be gone.

Comment: A lot of thanks! Moving to `initComponent` solved the case. Also many thanks for the articles!